# Clean URL with Laravel on primary domain only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, url-rewriting

I'm on a **shared hosting** account (no access to the more preferable solutions so I've got to go with a `.htaccess` rule.

When I implement the pretty URL to remove the public folder I get an `HTTP 500` error on subdomains.

I'm not versed enough in `.htaccess` to properly work out the rewrite rule(s) necessary. Can anyone help? My `.htaccess` looks as follows:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php55 .php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

edit:

What I want to accomplish:

http://example.com instead of http://example.com/public/

while excluding that from xsubdomain.example.com

> When I try going to the subdomains I do see the 500 error. When I
>   check the server's master error_log it tells me that my request is
>   exceeding the limit of 10 internal redirects.
>
> I found that you have a .htaccess file in the public_html directory
>   that is responsible. When I temporarily renamed that file I could
>   access both of the subdomains.
>
> It appears that you will need to set the .htaccess rules to only
>   affect the main directory or exclude the subdomain

---

Web Root .htacess

```
RewriteEngine On
# Don't do anything if it is blog subdomain for example.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /public/([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule .* /%1? [R=301,L]
```

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ public/$1 [L]

/public/ .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>


    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this in your .htaccess if you just want it for your main domain.

```
 AddType application/x-httpd-php55 .php
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    #Don't do anything if it is blog subdomain for example.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [L] 

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /public/([^&\ ]+)
    RewriteRule .* /%1? [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

You can do this so if you type in public it will redirect to URL without public. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Sub domains work, but the public folder is displayed again on main domain URLs.

Comment: @joseph what do you want exactly ? yourdomain.com/public should not work. is that what you need ?

Comment: @joseph if you don't enter the public folder it should not show. Are you entering the public folder in the browser and want it to not show if you type it in?

Comment: So it's a Laravel install and I can't set the docroot to the public folder. What I want to do is essentially hide the public directory (which is where the webroot should be). When I hide the public directory from the URL I get a 500 HTTP error on subdomains. So I want to disable the .htaccess rewrite rules for the subdomains.

Comment: That rule should disable subdomains and still allow you to hide public folder. What's not working now?

Comment: @PanamaJack HTTP 500 error on subdomains. I want subdomains to be accessible as I will display things like blogs, etc, on them.

Comment: You need to check your apache error_log to see why you are getting the 500 error. Without that we are guessing. Something else is probably the cause of that. If you can't get your logs, ask your host to see what the error is.

Comment: @joseph It might actually be trying to redirect your subdomain. Try my updated rule now. Otherwise check your logs.

Comment: Updating main post from host response.

Comment: You need to post ALL your larvel rules. I think that is the problem because you are leaving part of it out.

Comment: @PanamaJack Subdomains are operational but the /public/ in the URL is there still.

Comment: is still in what URL, subdomains or your main domain? and how are you entering the URL in the browser?

Comment: http://example.com redirects (PHP header) to http://example.com/public/ I want to mask the /public/ part of the URL. 


I never see /public/ on subdomains. When I get masking working on the main domain the subdomains break(500 Error).

Comment: @PanamaJack No change at all.

Comment: @joseph actually, since you already have the controller there, just change the directory for the controller rule to public/index.php. Then access your site without the public folder. I've updated the code.

Comment: @PanamaJack I get a 500 Internal Error now when accessing either example.com or example.com/public/

Comment: did you update all the rules or did you just update the very last part cuz I removed one rule.

Comment: @PanamaJack Sorry for the delay - I updated the entire file. I tried both on the root .htaccess and in the public folder's htaccess. Both resulted in the same thing. I really appreciate all the help.

Comment: @joseph I meant for you to use my entire set of rules in your root htaccess and don't use the one at all in the public folder.

Comment: @PanamaJack When I did that I got a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

using a .htaccess file is not the better way. for removing public from your url you should create a virtual host in your local server and the document root should be like this `DocumentRoot "h:\wamp\www\your_project_name\public"`

see [this](https://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp) how to create a virtual host in wamp.

Comment: If I had access to do this on the host, I would.

Comment: then open your paths.php file under bootstrap directory and find this `'public' => __DIR__.'/../public',` and replace with this `'public' => __DIR__.'/..',` it should work.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention this first of all copy all files from public directory, put them in your root folder, delete the public directory and then open your paths.php file under bootstrap directory and find this `'public' => __DIR__.'/../public',` and replace with this `'public' => __DIR__.'/..',` it should work.

Comment: If I can't get the .htaccess working I'll be sure to utilize this approach. Thanks very much!